# Submit form no longer working after adding checkbox list (.net mvc razor)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

I've added a checkbox list to an existing form, and now I can't submit it anymore. Is this because there's a data-val-required field added for the checkbox? If so, how can I fix it?

This is the code:

Output of a checkbox:

```
<input name="[0].Id" type="hidden" value="en" />
<input name="[0].Name" type="hidden" value="English" />
<div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChecked field is required." name="[0].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="[0].IsChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <label for="">English</label>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

Editor template:

```
@model CloudJunction.Web.MVC4.CloudJunction.Modules.CheckBoxViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsChecked, Model.Name)
</div>
```

Main view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // lots of other form items
    @Html.Partial("CheckboxList", Model.LanguageCheckboxes)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

I did notice that it creates an extra form tag, could that be causing the problems or is it simply ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is some *binding* or *build error* in the partial view. So when it will runned, there will be *an exception*, and the submit button is'nt rendering.

*Please check the output window*.

*Clean* and *rebuild* the code, and *check the partial view*, are there any error?

**If there is not error, than the nested form will the responsible for the issue**.

Comment: Can't see any errors unfortunately, and the submit button is rendering, it's just that nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: Then the nest form will your problem

Comment: Just remove the inner form. As I see you didnt use that for anything.

Comment: Go to the partial view and delete.  @using (Html.BeginForm()) with the brackets. And leave the editorformodel. Maybe it can be builted. If not i thinking forward :D

Comment: Sorry, I was being blind/stupid, will delete it now!

Comment: That is nothing, everyone do that ;)